# Generation of code based on the table meta data

Tags: java, oracle, struts2

Is there any free tool which can generate data entry and listing screen for a database table(Oracle) based on the metadata. Desired features:

- Drop downs for reference data
- Abilty to customise the label name, showing/hiding specific column of the table, ordering of columns etc..
- Operation on listing screen (modify,delete,activate,deactivate etc.)
- import the data from CSV file.
- Ability to add custom validation before save/modify the data in DB.
- Pre Delete Validations.
- Option to choose technology stack e,g, (Struts 2, Spring, Hibernate) or (Struts 1, EJB,DAO pattern) etc.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle database there is a tool called **APEX** that can generate views and edit pages starting from db structure.

This is the pointer: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/overview/index.html

But APEX has **its own technology stack** and it does not generate code, it's a Access-like framework to handle Oracle db data.

Answer (score 0):

As you are interested in Java technology I urge you to check out [JDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technology/jdev/index.html).  It gets over-looked by Java people because it's not Eclipse but it has lots of cool features.  In particular its ADF BC wizards can generate quite sophisticated data-driven components.  [Find out more.](http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/obe/jdev/obe11jdev/ps1/ria_application/developriaapplication_long.htm)

Oh, and the tool is free as in free beer, although there are licences payable to deploy ADF and TopLink components.  Thanks to carpenteri for pointing out [the relevant documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/jdeveloper11gfaq-085697.html#L0).

Comment: Quick question on ADF BC wizards. Are they free? The reason for asking is that I "heard" that ADF was free as long as you had an Oracle Weblogic license otherwise there was a cost involved. See this link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/jdeveloper11gfaq-085697.html#L0

Comment: @carpenteri - No, you're right.  My experience with them was using Oracle App Server (i.e. a while back), so I didn't realise they charged for deploying them in other environments.

Answer (score 0):

these exist ([www.enterprise-elements.com](http://www.enterprise-elements.com)) but are certainly not free.